# Django templates: optional variable in a with

Tags: django, django-templates

This might be a pretty simple question; but I can't seem to find the 'correct' approach.

I have a template, in which I include a different template three times. I pass quite a few variables along with the include. The problem is that one of them is optional.

```
{% with
    title="Add object"
    type="function"
    function_type="FUNCTION"
    inputs=function_create_form
    project_id=project.id
    parent_function_id=root_function.id
    {% if root_function.type == 'OBJECT' %}
        parent_function_id=root_function.id
    {% endif %}
%}
    {% include "./popup-form.html" %}
{% endwith %}
```

(I'm aware that this should be on one line in the template, for some reason. But this is way more readable.)

The gist of it is that I only want to pass the variable in the `if` statement, if it is of the correct type. It will always have a value, but not always the correct one. Sadly though, Django doesn't seem to tolerate if statements in `with`'s.

To clarify, the variable should only be passed to the template if it is of the correct type. The included template is a popup form used to add objects. These objects have different types; ROOM, OBJECT, and FUNCTION. These objects can in turn have a parent object, which is exactly what I want to pass. But this parent should only be passed to the popup form if the user is viewing the correct object type. This is determined by the if statement

I also tried to do this, same result:

```
{% include "./popup-form.html" with
    title="Add object"
    type="function"
    function_type="OBJECT"
    inputs=function_create_form
    project_id=project.id
    {% if root_function.type == 'OBJECT' %}
        parent_function_id=root_function.id
    {% endif %}
%}
```

Error: `'with' received an invalid token: '{%'`

I could perhaps make an `if` statement outside of the `with` and set the value of the variable to an empty string. But there ought to be a better way, right? Doing this in the `view` is not an option, since the variable will always need to have a value.

Comment: You could do this before rendering template: just pass `parent_function_id` ready to use.

Comment: I know this. The problem, I think I'm not being clear enough. I'll update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of this statement should be a clue that this is the wrong approach.

If you want to pass multiple variables to an included template, you should probably be looking at an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) instead. You can then use any combination of positional and keyword arguments to render the template.